# Suppose that X and Y are independent exponential random variables each with mean 1

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent exponential random variables each with mean $1.$ What is $P\!\left(Y > X^2\right)?$

Answer (score 5):

We have
\begin{align*}
f_X(x)
&=e^{-x}\\
f_Y(y)
&=e^{-y}\\
f(x,y)
&=\underbrace{f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)}_{\text{independent}}=e^{-(x+y)}\\
P\big(Y>X^2\big)
&=\int_0^\infty\int_{x^2}^\infty e^{-(x+y)}\,dy\,dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\int_{x^2}^\infty e^{-y}\,dy\,dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,e^{-x^2}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-x-x^2\right)\,dx\\
&=e^{1/4}\int_0^\infty e^{-(x+1/2)^2}\,dx \qquad \text{(complete the square)}\\
&=e^{1/4}\int_{1/2}^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt \qquad (x+1/2 = t,\; dx=dt)\\
&=\frac{e^{1/4}\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\,\operatorname{erfc}\!\left(\frac12\right)\\
&\approx 0.4249.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the answer using computer algebra packages such as Mathematica (Wolframalpha should work as well, but haven't tried). Here is the Mathematica code:

`dist = ExponentialDistribution[1];`

`Probability[y > x^2, {x \[Distributed] dist, y \[Distributed] dist}]`

The answer is:
$$\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[4]{e} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Here, $\texttt{erfc}$ is the complementary error function
$$ \text{erfc}(z) = 1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^z e^{-t^2}\,dt. $$